# Creating counts in a table with time component variables

Tags: r

Below is a subset of my data:

[image]

```
structure(list(ver = c("T4", "T5", "T6", "T4", "T5", "T6"), base = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), one = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), two = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), gradeT4base = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gradeT5base = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), gradeT4one = c(3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), gradeT5one = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), gradeT4two = c(2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2), gradeT5two = c(0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

- `base`=dummy variable, 1=first fracture at baseline, 0=first fracture not at baseline
- `one`=dummy variable, 1=first fracture at one year followup, 0=first fracture not one year followup
  ...
- `gradeT4base`= shows the grade for fracture at T4 vertebrae, 0=no fracture, 1=mild fracture, 2=severe fracture
  ...
- `grade T5one`= type of fracture at T5 vertebrae at 1 year followup, 0=no fracture, 1=mild fracture, 2=severe fracture

I need to create a table that shows the count of each vertebral body and grade of fracture ONLY when the first vertebral fracture occurred,

- The first vertebral fracture occurs where the first signs of a fracture happens.
- For example the second row, patient had their first vertebral fracture grade to be 1, at one year followup.
- Thus the first VF occurred at one year followup.

Example table using data above:

[image]

Some further explanation:
Looking at subject 6, first vertebral fracture was at 2 years where they had T4 of grade 2 and T5 of grade 1. Thus the count for Row T4 Grade 2 would increase by 1, and T5 Grade 1 would increase by 1.

- When first vertebral fracture occurs, I want to count how many fractures are of each grade in the two vertebral bodies. Looking at variables `base`, `one`, `two` tells us when the first vertebral fracture occurred,
- I want to sum the number of each fracture by grade.
- Looking at row 1, first VF occurred at baseline. We can see gradeT4base and gradeT5base for their grade assessments at baseline and gradeT4base has a value of 2.
- In my table of counts, row 2 of T4 with grade 2 would increase count by 1.
- The remaining values of this row will not be counted as we are only looking at first VF

Comment: Please provide your data using `dput()` instead of a picture.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate? Apologies, this is my first time using stackexchange. I ran the following and obtained the output below
> dput(dat)
structure(list(ver = c("T4", "T5", "T6", "T4", "T5", "T6"), base = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), one = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), two = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1), gradeT4base = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gradeT5base = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0), gradeT4one = c(3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), gradeT5one = c(0, 
0, 1, 2, 0, 0), gradeT4two = c(2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2), gradeT5two = c(0, 
1, 0, 3, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Comment: It is not clear to me how are you calculating the output here from the input.

Comment: What determines when the first vertebral fracture occurred?

Comment: The first vertebral fracture occurs where the first signs of a fracture happens. For example the second row, patient had their first vertebral fracture grade to be 1, at one year followup. Thus the first VF occurred at one year followup.

Comment: @AnilGoyal 6th column(gradeT5base) has a grade of 1, which means participant had a vertebral fracture at baseline in T5.

Comment: @RonakShah When first vertebral fracture occurs, I want to count how many fractures are of each grade in the two vertebral bodies.
Looking at variables base, one, two tells us when the first vertebral fracture occurred, I want to sum the number of each fracture by grade. 
Looking at row 1, first VF occurred at baseline. We can see gradeT4base nad gradeT5base for their grade assessments at baseline and gradeT4base has a value of 2. In my table of counts, row 2 of T4 with grade 2 would increase count by 1. The remaining values of this row will not be counted as we are only looking at first VF

Answer (score 0):

Finally I think I have figured it out

1. Approach 1

```
data %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('base'), ~ na_if(. * base, 0)),
         across(ends_with('one'), ~na_if(. * one, 0)),
         across(ends_with('two'), ~na_if(. * two, 0))) %>%
  select(starts_with('grade')) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = 'grade(T\\d+).*', 
               names_to = 'vert', values_to = 'grade', values_drop_na = T) %>%
  count(vert, grade, name = 'count') %>%
  complete(nesting(vert), grade = 1:3, fill = list(count = 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  vert  grade count
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 T4        1     1
2 T4        2     2
3 T4        3     0
4 T5        1     3
5 T5        2     1
6 T5        3     0
```

---

2. Approach -2

```r
data <- structure(list(ver = c("T4", "T5", "T6", "T4", "T5", "T6"), base = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), one = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), two = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), gradeT4base = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gradeT5base = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), gradeT4one = c(3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), gradeT5one = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0), gradeT4two = c(2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2), gradeT5two = c(0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(tidyverse)

data %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% select(-ver) %>%
  pivot_longer(!rowid, names_pattern = '(gradeT\\d)*(.*)', names_to = c('name', 'd')) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(name == '', 'dummy', name)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  filter(dummy == 1) %>% select(-c(d, dummy)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid, names_to = 'vert', values_to = 'grade') %>%
  filter(grade != 0) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(vert, grade, name = 'count') %>%
  complete(nesting(vert), grade = 1:3, fill = list(count = 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   vert    grade count
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 gradeT4     1     1
#> 2 gradeT4     2     2
#> 3 gradeT4     3     0
#> 4 gradeT5     1     3
#> 5 gradeT5     2     1
#> 6 gradeT5     3     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Question regarding approach 1, could you explain the reason for running pivot_longer?

Comment: @Brenda, yes! Grades in your input are actually variable names but variables in output. That's why pivot.